# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0. in android studio build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What should I do with this error in Android Studio?

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

I have this problem even in IntelliJ IDEA Has anyone been able to fix this error?

Comment: Usually for deprecated features that will be removed an alternative way to do the same is implemented. Have you tried to migrate your project to this new way?

Answer (score 1):

Considering Gradle version 9.0 hasnt even been released yet, I wouldnt worry about it too much.  This is a warning, not an error, but if you want to dive in further use --warning-mode all to see where this is originating from when running